# Can't load X11 in R after OS X Yosemite upgrade

Tags: r, macos, x11, osx-yosemite

Running into the following error when I try to use ggplot2 and plot within the console after upgrading to Yosemite:

```
Error in (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  : 
  X11 module cannot be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /usr/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
```

How can I go about resolving this?

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Did you reinstall XQuartz after updating?  Try reinstalling first before you do anything else.

Comment: Read the recent posts to r-sig-mac mailing list.  They'll point you to the appropriate info.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Execute the following in a terminal window:

```
locate libSM.6.dylib
```

or do it from an R console:

```
system("locate libSM.6.dylib")
```

On my Yosemite install it's in `/opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib`.

If your setup is similar, then:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/X11 /opt/X11
```

should help fix this temporarily, but I'd keep looking for a Yosemite R package (since that will accommodate all the changes Apple made to the filesystem structure).

Comment: You also need to setup the /usr/X11R6 symlink.  The easiest thing to do is just reinstall XQuartz which does that for you.

Comment: I had to reinstall XQuartz *and* open it (in order to fix the symlinks I guess).

Answer (score 40):

It looks like the OS update deleted the /usr/X11 and /usr/X11R6 symlinks.  Please just re-install XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org which will setup the symlinks again for you.

Comment: This should be the solution. AFAIK many apps require the reinstallation of XQuartz as well.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps won't work for everyone, i'm not even quite sure what the problem was, but I found the same error messages after installing Yosemite and was able to solve the problem simply by reinstalling XQuartz from http://xquartz.macosforge.org

Answer (score 3):

Had the same problem with R and OS X Yosemite (but with libpng15.15.dylib file).
For me the following steps were helpful:

- install latest XQuartz 2.7.7
- `sudo ln -s /opt/X11/lib/libpng15.15.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpng15.15.dylib`