# Fail to attach "treescape" package in R

Tags: r, tree, binary-tree, phylogeny

I did as the the follows below:

1.install package "devtools".

2.`library(devtools)`

`install_github("thibautjombart/treescape")`

Or using `install.packages("treescape")`

3.`library("treescape")`

However, this package cannot be attached and R gave me such a feedback:

```
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :

  there is no package called ‘Luminescence’
```

In addition:

```
Warning message:
package ‘treescape’ was built under R version 3.2.3 

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘treescape’
```

Then I tried to install "Luminescence" but the feedback was:

```
package ‘Luminescence’ is not available (for R version 3.2.1)
```

Then, I updated R to newest version, installed and attached luminescence package. When i tried to attach treescape, the new error appeared:

```
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rgl', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libGLU.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/rgl/libs/rgl.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘treescape’
```

Comment: See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Luminescence/index.html. Luminescence needs R>3.2.2: `Depends: R (≥ 3.2.2)`. Can you update you R version? Alternatively, download older version of Luminescence from archives.

Comment: yes. I did. this time luminescence was attached but treesscape still failed.  I add the new feedback in the post.

Comment: it's an rgl problem; try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28507111/error-running-the-packages-rgl-and-geomorph-on-r-on-mac ?

Comment: cool! thanks anyway! it was finally solved......

Comment: @CharlesYan can you explain how you solved your issue in an answer to your own question? That can be useful for others.

Comment: Sorry for such a late explanation. The problem was solved by installing the package rgl, which is used for plotting if I can remember.