# Can't load X11 in R after OS X Yosemite upgrade, not root

Tags: r, macos, root, x11, osx-yosemite

I get the following error message when I try to install some packages with R.

```
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
Error in setwd(cDir) : character argument expected
In addition: Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
Error in setwd(cDir) : character argument expected
```

This problem had been solved here :
[Can't load X11 in R after OS X Yosemite upgrade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489928/cant-load-x11-in-r-after-os-x-yosemite-upgrade)

My problem is that I do not have root access on this mac. Is there a way to solve this issue without root access ?

Thanks

Comment: If X was working before (hence, it was installed before), have the administrator remove and reinstall the XQuartz package.