# Error "cannot load shared object" on installing Hmisc in R on OS X Yosemite

Tags: r, macos

Executing `install.packages("Hmisc")` in R gives me the following error message:

```
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  impossible de charger l'objet partagé '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Apologies that my system is set to French: the third line beginning with "impossible de charger ..." means "cannot load the shared object ...".

My system is Mac OS X Yosemite (10.10.5). My R version is 3.2.2 64-bit. This is the first time I have tried to install a package on R on this computer with this operating system.

Comment: There's an extra / in those paths before the `R_X11.so`

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489928/cant-load-x11-in-r-after-os-x-yosemite-upgrade