# warning message when using Microsoft R Open 3.3.1 in MAC

Tags: r, package, x11, method-resolution-order

I am using Mac OS X EL Capitan 10.11.6 with Microsoft R Open 3.3.1.

After following the instructions for installation of MRO and having a fresh installation of `XQuartz 2.7.9`, I am having the following error whenever I want to install any R package, for example, when installing `MASS`, I am seeing the following warning message.  It seems like it does not affect the usage, but it is annoying to see this warning every time.

```
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Symbol not found: _CGBitmapContextCreate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
* installing *source* package ‘MASS’ ...
** package ‘MASS’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
```

Comment: I cannot test whether this applies to the MRO version of R on my the "standard" CRAN distribution of R 3.31 because the two are designed to conflict, but to my eyes this looks like you have not properly installed XQuartz  (OSX's X11 equivalent, and I think the current version is 2.7.9). Several people responding to an earlier similar question found that reinstalling XQuartz worked for them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26489928/cant-load-x11-in-r-after-os-x-yosemite-upgrade

Comment: That "location" is actually in a symlink directory and you should see R_X11.so if you navigate to `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/modules/R_X11.so`

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem when using Microsoft R Open 3.3.1 on macOS 10.12.

I refer to this link: 
[Warning message when opening RStudio or the R console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39618269/warning-message-when-opening-rstudio-or-the-r-console)

and replace `R_X11.so` with `R_X11.so` of CRAN R.

1. Go to [CRAN R for Mac OS X](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/), and download the installer(.pkg)
2. install the CRAN R.
3. you can find the `R_X11.so` of CRAN R at `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/modules/`
4. install MRO
5. replace `R_X11.so` of MRO(at `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3.1-MRO/Resources/modules/`) with `R_X11.so` of CRAN R(look step 3)

Comment: Can you provide more explicit details on how to do that?

Comment: 1. Go to [CRAN R for Mac OS X](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) download the installer

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with this comment system.it not support a newline? maybe I should edit my answer.

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer ... but stack won't let me comment!!

This directory /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/modul‌​es/

does not exist ... however:
/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3.1-MRO/Resources/modul‌​es/

Does exist ... perhaps that is the issue?