# Warning message when opening RStudio or the R console

Tags: r, rstudio, osx-elcapitan, microsoft-r

recently I installed Microsoft R Open 3.3.1 on my MacBook Pro (El Capitan 10.11.6). When I open RStudio or I use the R console I get this warning message:

```
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) :
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so, 6): Symbol not found: _CGBitmapContextCreate
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules//R_X11.so
```

Do you know a way to prevent the printing of the message (or solve the issue)?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a great question for Microsoft support. Does the error go away when you switch back to CRAN R?

Comment: I tried with the CRAN R version and in that case there is no warning.

Comment: @amarchin, As per https://github.com/IRkernel/IRkernel/issues/300, please try installing XQuartz from https://www.xquartz.org/.

Comment: @jav, unfortunately I have already tried this option but it didn't work for me.

Comment: I installed the latest version of Quartz and then MRO. Having the same problem on Oct 21, 2016

Comment: @amarchin did you try the Autobox version?

Answer (score 5):

For a CRAN R installation, I see that `R_X11.so` references the following libraries:

```
kevin@MBP:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules
$ otool -L R_X11.so
R_X11.so:
        R_X11.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.5)
        /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libxml2.2.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.9.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1197.1.1)
        /usr/lib/libbz2.1.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.5)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXt.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXmu.6.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.1)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 855.17.0)
```

That library does not reference the symbol you suggest:

```
kevin@MBP:/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules
$ nm R_X11.so | grep CGBitmap
```

However, for an MRO installation, I see the following libraries + symbols:

```
kevin@MBP:/Volumes/Samsung 850 EVO/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules
$ otool -L R_X11.so
R_X11.so:
        R_X11.so (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libSM.6.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.1.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libICE.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libX11.6.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXext.6.dylib (compatibility version 11.0.0, current version 11.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXrender.1.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libexpat.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.2.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXt.7.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
        /opt/X11/lib/libXmu.6.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.0.0)
        /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3.1-MRO/Resources/lib/libR.dylib (compatibility version 3.3.0, current version 3.3.1)
        /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation (compatibility version 150.0.0, current version 1255.1.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1225.1.1)
```

with referenced symbols:

```
kevin@MBP:/Volumes/Samsung 850 EVO/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/modules
$ nm R_X11.so | grep CGBitmap
                 U _CGBitmapContextCreate
```

These symbols are normally provided by the `CoreGraphics.framework`:

```
kevin@MBP:/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/Versions/A
$ nm CoreGraphics | grep CGBitmapContext
0000000000046321 T _CGBitmapContextCreate
< ... other symbols ... >
```

However, the MRO-generated `R_X11.so` does not link to that, and so lookup of those symbols fails.

tl;dr: Microsoft is shipping you broken software that does not contain links to the libraries providing the symbols it needs. Use the [CRAN-provided binaries of R](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue also. The issue had been solved after installing XQuartz and then re-logining the system.

Note: the use of X11 (including tcltk) requires [XQuartz](http://xquartz.macosforge.org/) to be installed since it is no longer part of OS X. Always re-install XQuartz when upgrading your OS X to a new major version.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where it couldn't find the `R_X11.so` file.

So I went into the terminal in RStudio and ran

```bash
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y
```

Then the problem went away. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377623/5783745) useful.