# ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run cv2, but when I try to import it, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

The suggested solution online is installing

```
apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
```

but this is already installed and the latest version.

NB: I am actually running this on Docker, and I am not able to check the OpenCV version. I tried importing matplotlib and that imports fine.

Comment: How did you install it? `pip install opencv-python`? Could be another issue. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/9954. Try creating a virtualenv and test it there. Can you share your code snippet where its throwing the exception?

Comment: But, `apt install libgl1-mesa-glx` helped me.

Comment: You should add "Docker" as part of the TITLE & TAGS of your question.
The correct answer for the TITLE of question is: "Install `apt install libgl1-mesa-glx`"
The title is misleading if you are NOT using docker. EDIT: I have done this for you.

Answer (score 796):

Add the following lines to your Dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

These commands install the cv2 dependencies that are normally present on the local machine, but might be missing in your Docker container causing the issue.

[minor update on 20 Jan 2022: as Docker recommends, never put `RUN apt-get update` alone, causing cache issue]

Comment: what does this do and why do I need it for cv2?

Comment: I got an error:
"E: Repository 'http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease' 
changed its 'Suite' value from 'stable-updates' to 'oldstable-updates'". 

I fixed it by using:
`sudo apt-get update --allow-releaseinfo-change`

Comment: This solution worked for me and then stopped working during Docker build. I changed my base image to python:3.8-slim-buster as suggested by @SuryaTej, which worked at first, but then stopped working as well. I thought maybe it was a network issue on my side, but the build fails more often than not.

> #8 254.6 Get:197 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster/main amd64 xdg-user-dirs amd64 0.17-2 [53.8 kB]
> #8 254.6 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libp/libpng1.6/libpng16-16_1.6.36-6_amd64.deb  Hash Sum mismatch
> #Last modification reported: Mon, 08 Apr 2019 10:11:25

Comment: the author has mentioned in the comments he is doing this in docker.
This command just installs the cv2 dependencies that are present on the local machine normally but might be missing in your docker causing the issue @wovano

Comment: This does not work for me. But the answer of Awanish Kumar Golware does

Comment: Per an answer below can use opencv-python-headless if you don't reuquire GUI functions, see here: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python/issues/370

Comment: nit: didn't need ffmpeg for me

Comment: For anyone working in Deepnote the instructions for extending the Dockerfile are [here](https://deepnote.com/docs/custom-environments#local-dockerfile)

Answer (score 233):

Even though the above solutions work. But their package sizes are quite big.
`libGL.so.1` is provided by package `libgl1`. So the following code is sufficient.

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1
```

Comment: I had same issue as described above but your solution sadly did not work for me.

Comment: This is a more concise solution compared to the accepted answer.

Comment: This worked for me in WSL Ubuntu, then to downgrade protobuf (slightly unrelated, but was my next bug), finally everything worked

Comment: This one works for me while the accepted answer does not because of various dependency issues.

Comment: Only solution that worked on Sagemaker AWS

Comment: Works on my side

Answer (score 131):

Try installing `opencv-python-headless` python dependency instead of `opencv-python`. That includes a precompiled binary wheel with no external dependencies (other than numpy), and is intended for headless environments like Docker. This saved almost 700mb in my docker image compared with using the `python3-opencv` Debian package (with all its dependencies).

The [package documentation](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/) discusses this and the related (more expansive) `opencv-contrib-python-headless` pypi package.

##### Example reproducing the `ImportError` in the question

```
# docker run -it python:3.9-slim bash -c "pip -q install opencv-python; python -c 'import cv2'"
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
# docker run -it python:3.9-slim bash -c "pip -q install opencv-python-headless; python -c 'import cv2'"
WARNING: Running pip as the 'root' user can result in broken permissions and conflicting behaviour with the system package manager. It is recommended to use a virtual environment instead: https://pip.pypa.io/warnings/venv
```

Comment: This is best answer!!  Works great! No need to fiddle around with apt-get or system install when you don;t have the permission to install system packages. Thanks!

Comment: It worked quite well in my case in order to build docker image of python environments in Azure ML. Thanks a million!!

Comment: Wow! Other answers required me installing >1GB of dependencies, this worked amazingly!

Comment: this got me past my error but then got another error: module 'cv2' has no attribute 'gapi_wip_gst_GStreamerPipeline' -- any idea what this means?

Comment: @Leigh I haven't seen that error, but this question looks relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72706073/attributeerror-partially-initialized-module-cv2-has-no-attribute-gapi-wip-gs

Comment: yep, it worked for me on **visual studio code github codespaces** too. recommend this. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 85):

This is a little bit better solution in my opinion. Package `python3-opencv` includes all system dependencies of OpenCV.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv
RUN pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: I'm using `python:buster`. the solution above didn't work for me: `ffmpeg` seems to be deprecated and I still had write errors.
`apt-get install -y python3-opencv` did the trick.
thanks

Comment: This gets just about every lib you could want. I didn't try it, but is pip install still needed?

Comment: @MarkCarpenterJr - Using pip will help you to keep the packed version in a defined state. If you use the version of the operating system, you might end up with changing dependencies if your distro is changing packages. This is probably not what you want.

Comment: This is absolutely the most stable approach. The ffmpeg issue is breaking the leading answer.

Comment: This is the one that worked for me. the `pip install opencv-python-headless` still gave me the same error. I'm also working in Docker.

Answer (score 42):

For me, the only WA that worked is following:

```
# These are for libGL.so issues
# RUN apt-get update
# RUN apt install libgl1-mesa-glx
# RUN apt-get install -y python3-opencv
# RUN pip3 install opencv-python
RUN pip3 install opencv-python-headless==4.5.3.56
```

Comment: thanks. And don't forget opencv-contrib-python-headless if you're using contrib

Answer (score 41):

If you're on CentOS, RHEL, Fedora, or other linux distros that use `yum`, you'll want:

```
sudo yum install mesa-libGL -y
```

In Arch this maps to extra/mesa:

```
sudo pacman -S mesa-libgl
```

Comment: This helps me out. Thank a lot.

Comment: This helped me a lot thank you

Comment: Thanks. This was especially useful for Amazon Linux.

Answer (score 19):

In my case it was enough to do the following which also saves space in comparison to [above solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377623)

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        libgl1 \
        libglib2.0-0 \
```

Comment: This takes indeed much less space. Works on ubuntu 20

Comment: worked on my docker ubuntu 20 image

Comment: Worked with my Docker base image `python:3.10.6-slim-buster`, thank you!

Answer (score 16):

Put this in the `Dockerfile`

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Before the line

```
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
```

For example

```
......

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt

......
```

Comment: can this lib `libgl1-mesa-glx` source code be downloaded and installed without sudo privileges?

Answer (score 9):

Use `opencv-python-headless` if you're using docker or in server environment.

Answer (score 6):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to use OpenCV in the GCP Appengine Flex server environment. Replacing "opencv-python" by "opencv-python-headless" in the requirements.txt solved the problem.

The [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/master/) talks about different packages for desktop vs. Server (headless) environments.

Answer (score 6):

I met this problem while using cv2 in a docker container. I fixed it by:

```
pip install opencv-contrib-python
```

install **[opencv-contrib-python](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-contrib-python/)** rather than **opencv-python**.

Comment: typo in the package name, but I can't edit it

Comment: At one point, I used [opencv-python-headless](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python-headless/) which worked for my case with FastAPI when I deployed on Heroku once. What's the difference between contrib and headless?

Answer (score 6):

### Watch the error message carefully

I got error:

```
ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

which is very similar to:

```
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Basically `libGL` become `libEGL` (extra `E`)

In this case you must install `libegl1` and not `libgl1`:

```bash
apt update && apt install libegl1 -y
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the solution you need:

```bash
pip install -U opencv-python
apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 ffmpeg libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libgl1-mesa-glx
```

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` updates all installed packages which is completely overkill

Comment: this works for me. yeah, please do consider the overkill

Answer (score 3):

This is how your docker files should like for building image on Linux 64

```
# Use Python 3.10 from the respective version as a parent image
FROM python:3.10 

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the contents of the your_code_directory into the container at /app
COPY your_code_directory /app

# Copy the requirements.txt file into the container at /app/requirements.txt

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt

# These are folder outside app if there is requirement for your application

COPY config /config
COPY your_folder /your_folder

# For fixing ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt install -y libgl1-mesa-glx

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Run app.py when the container launches
CMD ["python", "app.py"]
```

You should successfully be able to build the docker image

Answer (score 2):

had the same issue on centos 8 after using pip3 install opencv on a non gui server which is lacking all sorts of graphics libraries.

`dnf install opencv`

pulls in all needed dependencies.

Answer (score 2):

"installing opencv-python-headless instead of opencv-python"
this works in my case!
I was deploying my website to Azure and pop up this exception:
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
then I uninstall the opencv-python package, install the later one,
freeze the requirements and then deploy it again,
then problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

I am also installing OpenCV through pip, in a Docker container. I use a Python3.11 base image (Ubuntu host on Jetson). After installing `libgl1-mesa-glx`, like you, I was prompted with another dependency error. The suggested solution from **@Tushar Kolhe** worked for me.

Though if you don't want to install the other packages suggested therein, I found installing `libopencv-dev` also works. Optionally, you might want to include two other lines: one to clean up the package manager's cache, and one to remove package lists, possibly reducing the resulting Docker image size, depending on what other packages you hope to install:

```
RUN apt update && \
    apt install -y libopencv-dev && \
    apt clean && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Answer (score 1):

For a raspberry pi, put this , work for me :

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was related to proxy setting. For pypi, I was using nexus mirror to pypi, for opencv nothing worked. Until I connected to a different network.

Answer (score 1):

This command works for me.

```
apt-get install libgl1
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had this issue. I am not even using docker, I used requirements.txt and even after adding open-cv-headless, it didn't worked for me.
I changed my hosting platform to `render.com` and it worked.

NB: if you are using Docker and wants to switch to headless version of oprn cv,
use version `4.8.1.78` or lower. The updated one is not working as of January 2024.

Answer (score 0):

In rocky linux 9 i resolved the error using command
`dnf install mesa-libGLU`

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue on Ubuntu desktop, and none of the other solutions worked for me.

`libGL.so.1` was correctly installed but for some reason Python wasn’t able to see it:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so.1
    libGL.so.1 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so.1
```

The only solution that worked was to force it in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Add the following in your `~/.bashrc` then run `source ~/.bashrc` or restart your shell:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```

I understand that [`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is bad](http://xahlee.info/UnixResource_dir/_/ldpath.html) but for me this is the only solution that works.