# Opencv not installing?

Tags: opencv, pycharm, deepnote

I've tried to install cv2 into deepnote and also into Pycharm using the following code - but nothing seems to work? Is cv2 not installable anymore? I've been using it up till last week and it was working fine but it doesn't seem to work anymore.

```
!pip install opencv-python
!pip install --upgrade pip

import cv2 # openCV for computer vision
import numpy as np # numpy for arrays
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt # matplotlib for plotting
```

Anyone have any idea what has happened? I've not changed any code whatsoever. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked code is correct. In some environments (like Deepnote), however, you have to install extra dependencies as suggested [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63377623/1893452).

```
!apt update
!apt install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

Here's [an example notebook](https://deepnote.com/project/436378e9-cd9b-410e-84f9-f379d55f07fa) of this working properly. Specifically in Deepnote, you can move the `apt` and `pip` install calls into a Custom environments Dockerfile.

In the future, please be more specific about what is not working.

Comment: Thank you Jakub! And I will do - I'm fairly new to using the website!