# How to resolve ImportError?

Tags: python, server, importerror, opencv

I have written a python code in which I am using opencv-python. The code is perfectly running on my local machine. I am trying to make it live by uploading it on a server.

File "/var/www/xxxx/xxxxx/xxxxx/imgmask.py", line 2, in 
import cv2 as cv
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I resolve this problem? Please help!!

Note: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Have you installed opencv-python on the server?

Comment: I am so glad to see your comment. And yes, I did. But I think there are 2-3 versions of python installed on server. I don't think it must be creating a problem, Is it?

Comment: Maybe take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo

Comment: Okay, I will check it. Should I run that command to install it globally or in specific folder?

Answer (score 0):

If you use pipenv, you should write on terminal: `pip install opencv-python`

Answer (score 0):

In the file you are importing `cv2` copy the following code and paste and run it.

```
try:
   import cv2
except Exception as e:
   from pip._internal import main
   main(["install", "opencv-python"])
finally:
   pass
```

Good Luck, let me know if it works