# ImportError: libGL.so.1 when running Docker container with OpenCV

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, opencv, apt

I'm getting the following error when running my docker container:

```
  W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libcudart.so.11.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.11.0: cannot open shared object file: No such fi
le or directory
2021-07-01 18:39:36.985933: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/program/analyze", line 4, in <module>
    from analysis.image_data_analyzer import ImageDataAnalyzer
  File "/opt/program/analysis/image_data_analyzer.py", line 1, in <module>
    from alibi_detect.utils.saving import save_detector, load_detector
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alibi_detect/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from . import ad, cd, models, od, utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alibi_detect/od/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .llr import LLR
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alibi_detect/od/llr.py", line 13, in <module>
    from alibi_detect.utils.perturbation import mutate_categorical
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/alibi_detect/utils/perturbation.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried running the following commands as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo).

```
RUN apt-get update ##[edited]
RUN apt-get install ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
```

However, I get the error `/bin/sh: apt-get: command not found`. I also tried installing libGL with yum, but that also did not work. The parent image of this container is linux. Any ideas on how to solve this error? Thank you.

Comment: docker prevents you from using various resources, graphics display (OpenGL) being one of them. it's a known issue. don't use docker unless you have to.

Comment: the project requires docker. it seems that it's possible to run opengl in docker (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo), but the apt-get commands are not working for me.

Comment: `apt-get: command not found` means you don't have `apt`. what distribution is this?

Comment: how do you find that out using docker?

Comment: `lsb-release` and `uname`, perhaps with additional arguments https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-check-os-version-in-linux-command-line/

Comment: What's the `FROM` line at the top of your Dockerfile? (Really, for a [mre], you should be providing the entire Dockerfile in the question itself).

Comment: The best solution for this problem is presented [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69125651/5127304) which gives you a way to use a precompiled binary wheel with no external dependencies for the cases like Docker containers.

Comment: Installing `mesa-libGL` as [Charles Duffy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68262468/20581881) also worked for me!

Comment: Installing `mesa-libGL` as [Charles Duffy suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68262468/20581881) also works for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved issue by adding this line to the Dockerfile: `RUN yum -y install mesa-libGL`

Comment: That means you're using a RPM-based distro instead of a Debian-based one. (`yum` is appropriate for Red Hat / Fedora / etc; `apt-get` is for Debian / Ubuntu / etc).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was creating a python server with flask, that uses the `cv2` from OpenCV to analyze images, and I managed to solve this problem by using the `python:3.9-slim-buster` docker image (that is light version of python full image, only with the necessary dependencies for the Python runtime) and installing the `opencv-contrib-python` package (you can get a description of this package [here](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/)). Also I manage to install some apt packages needed by OpenCV, there are `libsm6`, `libxext6`, `ffmpeg`, `libfontconfig1`, `libxrender1`, `libgl1-mesa-glx`.

I've also tested with the `python:3.8-slim-buster` docker image with the same Dockerfile structure and it's worked fine.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.9-slim-buster

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .
RUN apt update && apt install -y libsm6 libxext6 ffmpeg libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "python3", "/app/main.py" ]
```

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
numpy
opencv-contrib-python
python-dotenv
```

Just in case, the `numpy`, `Flask`, and `python-dotenv` is not necessary to install, I'm installing here because I need it in my python service.

I've seen a couple issues about it, but not a definitive answer. Some ways works for some people, some ways not.

I hope it helps.