# Packages not visible after venv added

Tags: python, pip, python-venv

I've installed `.venv` into my python project. I've activated it and then installed from requirments:

```
python -m venv .ven
.\.ven\Scripts\activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

when i run `pip3 list` i see all packages installed. Nevertheless when trying to run my application i see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Projekty/_Python/therobertseye/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from website import create_app
  File "d:\Projekty\_Python\therobertseye\website\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

in my _*init*.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from os import path
from flask_login import LoginManager
```

but its not only `Flask` - when i did remove for testing purpose :

```
from flask import Flask
```

then when ran again i see:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:/Projekty/_Python/therobertseye/app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from website import create_app
  File "d:\Projekty\_Python\therobertseye\website\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_sqlalchemy'
```

Means none of my packages are visible. Looks like libraries in venv are not visible? How can i sovle it?

I run my project from app.py by `python3.8.exe app.py`

app.py:

```
from website import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**EDIT:**
as stated by *@np8* both commands works on local:

```
python app.py
.\.ven\Scripts\python.exe app.py
```

Nevertheless when deployed on Azure i got errors in log:

```
021-12-11T10:11:56.228062960Z     from website.Barcode import Barcode
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228068661Z   File "/tmp/8d9bc8c8ae34714/website/Barcode.py", line 2, in <module>
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228074361Z     import cv2
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228079661Z   File "/tmp/8d9bc8c8ae34714/antenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228085161Z     from .cv2 import *
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228090161Z ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
2021-12-11T10:11:56.228096061Z [2021-12-11 10:11:56 +0000] [41] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 41)
2021-12-11T10:11:56.497660146Z [2021-12-11 10:11:56 +0000] [39] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2021-12-11T10:11:56.497793247Z [2021-12-11 10:11:56 +0000] [39] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
/home/LogFiles/2021_12_11_10-30-0-5_docker.log
```

Comment: How do you run your project? The venv is activated before running the project in the same circumstances?

Comment: @AliIrani i run my project running app.py - see in main post i enclosed it. python3.8.exe app.py. venv seems to be activated i see it in terminal

Comment: Would you please add the below solution to your code to see what packages are installed when you run your project? Add code from importing `create_app` in your `app.py` file.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23885252/10910984

Comment: Add `import sys; print(sys.executable)` to the top of your scipt to see if you are really using the python.exe from the `.ven` folder.

Comment: @np8 it shows: C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\python.exe How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You are using different python executable than the one in the virtual environment. When you type `python3.8.exe` in cmd or powershell, Windows will try to look for an executable called `python3.8.exe`(*). It goes through a list of folders and these folders are in your Windows `PATH` variable.

How virtual environments work (partly) is that there will be a `python.exe` in the `venv/Scripts` folder. When you run the virtual environment activate script, the `Scripts` folder is added to the `PATH` of the current process (cmd or powershell).  It is added to the *top* of the PATH so the python.exe in the venv will be the first one to be found.

Now, apparently there is no `python3.8.exe` in the virtual environment folder but a `python.exe`. Most probably just running

```
python app.py
```

will work (when virtual environment is activated in the vurrent process). If not, you can use

```
.\.ven\Scripts\python.exe app.py
```

which will always work even without activating the virtual environment.

(*)As a side note: the `python3.8.exe` thing is a Windows-specific thing. It is kind of a global shortcut called `python3.8.exe` which will point to a `python.exe` with correct version in a special place, as you saw yourself.

Comment: yes, when i do like this: .\venv\Scripts\python.exe .\app.py  then works (on local) as well as if i run python .\app.py

Comment: so using ur two commands worked on local but once after i deployed on azure i see errors (see main post) whats going on?

Comment: Are you running a Windows or Linux machine on Azure? Did you try googling our your importerror? Seems that OpenCV has not been installed correctly. See, for example [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)

Comment: scode installs linux container on publish. And yes i checked this link before and even run manualy and installed it on container, that not helped.