# Problems import CV2 package

Tags: python, opencv, import, package, importerror

I'm relatively new to image analysis and I want to import the CV2 package. When I run the code `import cv2` I receive the following error code:

`ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

I've looked at answers like this: [ImportError: libGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo)

But when I do, the solutions doesn't work For example one solution suggested to run `apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3-opencv`, but again, when I do, the code does not run. I already tried to uninstall the packages but still the same error.

Someone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may not have it installed via PyPi. I don't know CV2, but should be able to help you. First, go to https://pypi.org and search for the CV2 package because I don't know which one you are trying to use. Then click the copy button next to the console command and go to your command prompt or terminal and paste it there.

Comment: I used ```pip install opencv-python``` to instal openCV where cv2 is part of. But still get the same error message...

Comment: I just checked their PyPI page, they have more advanced install instructions and it says to make sure you did all of these if you get any other import errors.

Answer (score 0):

remove opencv from your environment first.
run

```
apt-get update && apt-get install libgl1
```

and then "pip install python3-opencv

Comment: I receive the error ```invalid syntax``` pointing to the 'u' of 'update'. So jupyter doesn't recognize this as a line of executable code. I work on ipynb file in jupyter lab.

Comment: @PaulEngelbert are you working on windows or linux?

Comment: I work on MacOS

Comment: @PaulEngelbert then no need to use apt-get command, I'd suggest using anaconda environments.

Comment: It still doesnt work. When I run your code it mentions: 'unknown command ''update''. When I try to leave it out and reinstall python3-opencv, loading the cv2 package still gives the same error