# Getting extremely confusing error even though all code seems to be okay, with correct syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

getting extremely confusing error even though all code seems to be okay, with correct syntax. Any help? Im pretty new to programming and  Im getting this error when I run it, (Im using reple.it btw):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "main.py", line 3 in <module>
   from  PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
ImportError: libGL.so.1:cannot open shared object file:
no such file directory
```

and my code is:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
 
 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
        self.setCentralWidget(self.browser)
        self.showMaximized()
 
        navbar = QToolBar()
        self.addToolBar(navbar)
        back_btn = QAction('Back', self)
        back_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.back)
        navbar.addAction(back_btn)
 
        forward_btn = QAction('Forward', self)
        forward_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.forward)
        navbar.addAction(forward_btn)
 
        reload_btn = QAction('Reload', self)
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(self.browser.reload)
        navbar.addAction(reload_btn)
 
        home_btn = QAction('Home', self)
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        navbar.addAction(home_btn)
 
        self.url_bar = QLineEdit()
        self.url_bar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)
        navbar.addWidget(self.url_bar)
 
        self.browser.urlChanged.connect(self.update_url)
 
    def navigate_home(self):
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl('https://google.com'))
 
    def navigate_to_url(self):
        url = self.url_bar.text()
        self.browser.setUrl(QUrl(url))
 
    def update_url(self, q):
        self.url_bar.setText(q.toString())
 
 
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
QApplication.setApplicationName("Adrians first browser")
window = MainWindow()
app.exec()
```

Any fixes? (Sorry if my question is stupid, I'm still new to coding

Comment: How did you install pyqt? If you're on linux, use the official packages provided by your distro, and avoid installing it via pip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not that silly. Basically, libGL.so.1 is a dynamic-linked library, provided from package `libgl1`.

Assuming you're on Linux, on a Debian or Ubuntu machine, a first step would be:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgl1
```

That might not be sufficient, and in that case, silly or not, I strongly encourage you to Google the exact error: you would have found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo), which gives you alternatives to solve your problem (if you're new to programming, it's something to keep in mind!).