# Why do the PySide6 Qt modules cause Tox to fail during a GitHub Action?

Tags: python, github-actions, pyside, tox

I have a python project that I am trying to test with Tox in GitHub Actions. Unfortunately the package PySide6 and its Qt modules causes Tox to fail when I have any python file that has any kind of import such as the following:

`from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication`

The issue seems to be the fact that PySide6's Qt modules cannot be located/opened/or something else during the github action run. If I change the import to simply `import PySide6` (or only use any other package like pandas for example) and run my tox github action again, everything passes successfully.

I looked at PySide6's `__init__.py` and noticed that it seems to load its Qt modules in a non-traditional way and was wondering if that had something to do with it.

Regardless, here is the error message I get from tox in github actions when I have something like `from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication` in my code...

```
  Installing the current project: hpm_test (0.0.1)
  py311: commands[1]> pytest --doctest-modules tests --cov --cov-config=pyproject.toml --cov-report=xml
  ============================= test session starts ==============================
  platform linux -- Python 3.11.2, pytest-7.2.1, pluggy-1.0.0
  cachedir: .tox/py311/.pytest_cache
  rootdir: /home/runner/work/hpm-test/hpm-test
  plugins: cov-4.0.0
  collected 0 items / 2 errors
  
  ==================================== ERRORS ====================================
  ______________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_foo.py ______________________
  tests/test_foo.py:3: in <module>
      from hpm_test.foo import foo, pan_check
  hpm_test/foo.py:2: in <module>
      from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
  E   ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  ______________________ ERROR collecting tests/test_foo.py ______________________
  ImportError while importing test module '/home/runner/work/hpm-test/hpm-test/tests/test_foo.py'.
  Hint: make sure your test modules/packages have valid Python names.
  Traceback:
  /opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.11.2/x64/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py:126: in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  tests/test_foo.py:3: in <module>
      from hpm_test.foo import foo, pan_check
  hpm_test/foo.py:2: in <module>
      from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication
  E   ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  
  ---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.11.2-final-0 -----------
  Coverage XML written to file coverage.xml
  
  =========================== short test summary info ============================
  ERROR tests/test_foo.py - ImportError: libEGL.so.1: cannot open shared object...
  ERROR tests/test_foo.py
  !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 2 errors during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  ============================== 2 errors in 0.77s ===============================
  py311: exit 2 (1.30 seconds) /home/runner/work/hpm-test/hpm-test> pytest --doctest-modules tests --cov --cov-config=pyproject.toml --cov-report=xml pid=1890
  py311: FAIL code 2 (3.93=setup[0.87]+cmd[1.76,1.30] seconds)
  evaluation failed :( (4.01 seconds)
Error: Process completed with exit code 2.
```

I can see that PySide6 and it's Qt modules do get installed by pip successfully before this test is run so I can't figure out why I'm getting the error. I even forcefully install the modules before the test to make sure they are in the environment:

```
      - name: Manually install PySide6 modules
        run: |
          python -m pip uninstall pyside6 shiboken6 PySide6-Essentials PySide6-Addons
          python -m pip cache purge
          python -m pip install pyside6 shiboken6 PySide6-Essentials PySide6-Addons
```

I was initially led [to this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55313610/importerror-libgl-so-1-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-directo/63377623#63377623) but I don't know if it applies to my situation and I'm not using docker and don't know how to convert this to a solution for me anyways.

(And by the way of course, running the `tox` command locally produces no errors in any situation.)

How do I resolve my error with the PySide6 package causing this issue with Tox in GitHub Actions?

Comment: Relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616065/the-imported-target-qt5gui-references-the-file-usr-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-li

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sure if this relates, but I had a similar issue with "libEGL.so.1 not found" when running unittests in a Github Action for a repo that used PySide6. My issue came from `PySide6.QtUiTools import loadUiType`, and it seems this depended on the libEGL.so.1.

I added an additional step in my Workflow File:

```
  - name: Install dependencies
    run: |
      sudo apt update && sudo apt install -y libegl1-mesa-dev
```

And that seemed to solve the issue. Hopefully that might help you out as well?

Comment: with PyQt5 I had added `libglu1-mesa-dev` but with PySide6 I added `libegl1-mesa-dev` and it worked!