# RStudio on Mac OS X 10.13 getting X11 is not available error when trying to use fix()

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I have installed XQuartz on my machine using homebrew and then I restarted my machine, when I try to use the fix() command in RStudio I get the following error

```
> College=read.csv("College.csv",header=T,na.strings ="?")
> fix(College)
Error in edit.data.frame(get(subx, envir = parent), title = subx, ...) : 
  X11 is not available
```

When I try to the following in terminal it works as expected. How can I make the same command work in RStudio

Comment: Did you try uninstalling the Homebrew version and using the actual installer? I have been using 10.13 since early alphas and XQuartz has been functioning perfectly (including just now when I tried `fix()`. As an aside, it's better to programmatically mutate the data than use something like `fix()` since you get reproducibility as a benefit.

Comment: Yes I did use the actual installer before I used the homebrew version and I still got the same problems. I then reinstalled XQuartz with homebrew. I wanted to use `fix()` because it is used in a book that I'm reading.

Comment: Is XQuartz running when you try to use `fix()`?

Comment: How do I do that? What I did try is running the command `x11()` in RStudio, the output was `Error in x11() : X11 is not available`

Comment: thee's an XQuartz app in `/Applications/Utilities/XQuartz.app`. Open it and then try to use X11 ops in R. It should have opened automatically. Also check https://stackoverflow.com/a/26490114/1457051

Comment: @hrbrmstr I tried doing the command with Xquartz open and the error still occurred. I even tried reinstalling it again through the installer. I also followed the answer in the above link and the same thing happened. I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19009308/cant-use-either-view-or-edit-functions-getting-error-in-external2c-data), I typed `locale` into terminal and all my values were `en_IE.UTF-8` instead of `C` like in the answer. Maybe this is the problem? Also, what other information can I give that help towards solving this problem?

Comment: Did you happen to install R via homebrew as well? https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/issues/5485 suggests it doesn't compile with X11 support out of the box anymore.

Comment: @hrbrmstr Yes I did, I uninstalled it and reinstalled it again using the installer from the R website and now it works. Thanks very much!

Comment: If you're using Homebrew, there's a tap that install R with X11 (and cairo) https://github.com/randy3k/homebrew-r#installing-r-with-x11-support

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Putting this as an answer in case other find this.

This particular issue was due to using Homebrew R on macOS which (at the time of this Q) didn't compile with X11 support.

I should have had the OP execute `capabilities()` first. That would have displayed something like:

```
##       jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua    http/ftp 
##       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
##    sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv         NLS     profmem 
##       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
##      cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
##       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

If `X11` is `FALSE`, then you have an R installation w/o support for X11 and should use the macOS R distribution from CRAN.