# R: The foreach does not work with exporting figure out, such as png or ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2, foreach, parallel-processing

I am trying to run `foreach` and `doParallel` in my local machine (Mac Pro 2009 with 12 cores or Macbook Pro 2017). Once there is plot or device-out, such as png or ggsave, the foreach stucked --- deadlock.

**UPDATE on Aug 29 2019**: I made a simple test:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)
registerDoParallel(cores = 4)
ret.plot=foreach(i = 1:4) %dopar% {
  write(1:1, paste0(i, '_p.txt'))
  md=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10); 
  p=ggplot(md, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point();
}

# for(i in 1:4){
ret.save1=foreach(i = 1:4) %do% {
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, '_do.png'), ret.plot[[i]])
}

ret.save2=foreach(i = 1:4) %dopar% {
  ggsave(filename = paste0(i, '_dopar.png'), ret.plot[[i]])
}

# ret.save2=foreach(i = 1:4, .packages = c("ggplot2")) %dopar% {
#   ggsave(filename = paste0(i, '_dopar.png'), ret.plot[[i]])
# }
```

The 1st parallel loop `ret.plot=...` works, that exports four .txt files, and return the list of `ggplot` results. 
The 2nd loop, both `for(i in 1:4)` or `foreach` with `%do%` work pefectly. 
BUT, the 3rd loop, `foreach` with `%dopar%` stucks again.

So it indicates 1)the parallel works alright in my machine, and 2) there may be a compatible issue between plot functions (`base::plot` or `ggsave`) and parallel.

The activity monitor on Mac shows four `rsession` are runing background and the CPU fan works harder. There is no difference in R in Terminal or RStudio.

---

Original question description:

```
Session information:

> sessionInfo() R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) Platform:
> x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0 (64-bit) Running under: macOS High Sierra
> 10.13.6
> 
> Matrix products: default BLAS:  
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
> LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.7/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.7.dylib
> 
> locale: [1]
> en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
> 
> attached base packages: [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices
> utils     datasets  methods   base     
> 
> other attached packages: [1] ggplot2_3.2.1     doParallel_1.0.15
> iterators_1.0.12  foreach_1.4.7    
> 
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.1      
> codetools_0.2-16 withr_2.1.2      assertthat_0.2.1  [5] dplyr_0.8.3   
> crayon_1.3.4     R6_2.4.0         grid_3.6.1        [9] gtable_0.3.0  
> magrittr_1.5     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.4.2     [13] rlang_0.4.0   
> lazyeval_0.2.2   rstudioapi_0.10  tools_3.6.1      [17] glue_1.3.1    
> purrr_0.3.2      munsell_0.5.0    compiler_3.6.1   [21]
> pkgconfig_2.0.2  colorspace_1.4-1 tidyselect_0.2.5 tibble_2.1.3



library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)
fxp<- function(x){
  png(paste0(x, '_p.png')) ;
  plot(1:10);
  dev.off()
}
fxg <-function(x){ 
  md=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10); 
  p=ggplot(md, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point();
  ggsave(filename = paste0(x, '_g.png'), p)
}
fxp(0);fxg(0)

cl <- 4
registerDoParallel(cl)
x=foreach(i =1:4) %dopar% {
  # for( i in 1:2){
  fxp(i);
  fxg(i)
}
```

There is no error, but program stops in the `foreach`.

**Test1:** If I run `fxp()` only and turn `plot(1:10)` OFF, the program works.

**Test2:** If I run `fxg()` only and turn `ggsave` OFF, the program works.

**Test3:** Once `plot` or `ggsave` is ON, the program enter deadlock in the foreach.

The test on another Linux machine (a cluster machine) with identical code works correctly always.
The session information of the Linux cluster is:

> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05) Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
>   Running under: Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
>
> Matrix products: default BLAS:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openblas/libblas.so.3 LAPACK:
>   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopenblasp-r0.2.20.so
>
> locale:  [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C
>   [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8      [5]
>   LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8     [7]
>   LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                   [9]
>   LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             [11]
>   LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C
>
> attached base packages: [1] parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices
>   utils     datasets  methods   [8] base
>
> other attached packages: [1] ggplot2_3.2.1     doParallel_1.0.15
>   iterators_1.0.12  foreach_1.4.7
>
> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):  [1] Rcpp_1.0.2
>   codetools_0.2-16 withr_2.1.2      crayon_1.3.4      [5] grid_3.6.1
>   gtable_0.3.0     scales_1.0.0     pillar_1.4.2      [9] rlang_0.4.0
>   lazyeval_0.2.2   labeling_0.3     tools_3.6.1      [13] munsell_0.5.0 
>   compiler_3.6.1   pkgconfig_2.0.2  colorspace_1.4-1 [17] tibble_2.1.3

---

Comment: Try running with cl = detectCores() -1 instead and see if you replicate the error. You may be depleting all your resources if your machine has only 4-cores in MAC.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It makes no difference. If I use one core ( only, it works. If I change the %dopar% to %do%, it works.

Comment: Ok. We eliminated that. I think another crucial step is to load packages locally inside each cluster. So please add library(ggplot2) inside foreach. x=foreach(i =1:4, .packages = c("ggplot2")) %dopar% etc. After this please run the code as it is. If unsuccessful,  repeat your Test 1-3 sequentially to find out how this change responds.

Comment: Since you're using `registerDoParallel(4)` and are on macOS (same on Linux), you're ending up with _forked_ parallel processing similar to `parallel::mclapply()`.  If you can reproduce this with `parallel::mclapply()` alone, you can rule out that foreach/doParallel is the problem.

Comment: Also, it is known that _forked_ parallel processing is non-reliable when using RStudio (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/2597#issuecomment-482187011).

Comment: Any update, @LeleShu?

Comment: Thanks, @VitaliAvagyan. I tested it. I don't think the problem is due to the package load inside of parallel, because, without ggplot2, the code with base::plot() alone does not work properly. I updated a simpler test.

Comment: Thanks. @HenrikB. After more test, I know the parellel code works well without any plot functions.  Once there is plot() or ggsave(), the parallel never end.

Answer (score 3):

I've expected the same issue using **png()** in a **%dopar%** on Mac OS (linux and Windows work fine).

This is somethings due to forking mechanism and graphics device on Mac Os (and maybe **png()** implementation).
If you do some things like this, you will see that no new graphics device is created by png:

```
fxp<- function(x){
    print(dev.cur())
    png(paste0(x, '_p.png')) ;
    print(dev.cur())
    plot(1:10);
    dev.off()
}

## quartz_off_screen
##               2
```

It seems that "*quartz*" can't open new graphic device in fork mode.
Let try with "*Xlib*" *png(type="Xlib")*, what a lovely message :

> "a forked child should not open a graphics device"

This confirms our doubts... but it "*should not*" not "*can't*"

## Solutions

### Use 1 core

Use %dopar% with *1* core works but this is not very useful.

```
cl <- 1
registerDoParallel(cl)
```

### So lets try with "*cairo*" :

```
fxp<- function(x){
    png(paste0(x, '_p.png'), type = "cairo", bg = "white") ;
    plot(1:10);
    dev.off()
}
```

> It's working ! (for me on Mac OS)

Comment: Thank you jfrey. Yes, I should use type='cairo'.  Besides your suggestion, I must use the R from r-project.org instead of homebrew.

Answer (score 0):

Thank @jfrey, You are right. I have to use cairo. Also, it require X11.

Here is something I found and solves my problem. 
1. install R from r-project instead of homebrew.
2. type = 'cairo' as jfrey suggested.

The R on my Mac is installed from homebrew, so the `capabilities()` return X11=FALSE. 
Then I uninstalled the R from homebrew, then download and install the R for Mac from https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/. Then the `capabilities()` returns `X11=TRUE`.

Then the parallel code with type='cairo' works perfectly on my Mac.

```
 capabilities()



     jpeg         png        tiff       tcltk         X11        aqua 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
   http/ftp     sockets      libxml        fifo      cledit       iconv 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE 
        NLS     profmem       cairo         ICU long.double     libcurl 
       TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE        TRUE
```

A thread might be useful: [RStudio on Mac OS X 10.13 getting X11 is not available error when trying to use fix()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47898202/rstudio-on-mac-os-x-10-13-getting-x11-is-not-available-error-when-trying-to-use?noredirect=1&lq=1)

I confirmed with code blow:

```
library(foreach)
library(doParallel)
library(ggplot2)
fxp<- function(x){
  png(paste0(x, '_p.png'), type = "cairo") ;
  plot(1:10);
  dev.off()
}
fxg <-function(x){ 
  md=data.frame(x=1:10, y=1:10); 
  p=ggplot(md, aes(x=x, y=y))+geom_point();
  ggsave(filename = paste0(x, '_g.png'), p, type = "cairo")
}
fxp(0);fxg(0)

cl <- 4
registerDoParallel(cl)
x=foreach(i =1:4) %dopar% {
  fxp(i);
  fxg(i)
}
```